# How to create a Panorama/360 Image Capture Camera in React Native

Tags: java, android, ios, react-native, mobile

I am working on a React Native project and I want to implement a panorama or 360-image capturing camera feature. I'm wondering if there are any libraries or techniques available for achieving this in React Native. btw is there is any way we can trigger mobile built-in panorma mode into our app on natively. then we can create a custom native module for react native :)

I am trying to build a camera that takes multiple pictures on multiple orientations using a gyroscope and then we combine all photos using some sought of functionality. but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.